# Showing the relationship between age and Gender on a bar chart

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm working on a visualization project and I've been trying to show the relationship between age and Gender on a bar chart, I've been stuck trying to make a bar chart showing the number of men and women for each age-range on the bar chart

This is what my data looks like:

|  | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35-39 | Man |
| 2 | 30-34 | Man |
| 3 | 35-39 | Man |
| 4 | 30-34 | Man |
| 5 | 30-34 | Man |
| … | … | … |
| 20032 | 18-21 | Man |
| 20033 | 55-59 | Woman |
| 20034 | 30-34 | Man |
| 20035 | 22-24 | Man |
| 20036 | 22-24 | Man |

Comment: Hi @Timilehin. Your question is not focused on a specific programming language or visualization tool. There are thousands of different ways to visualize things. I recommend you do some googling and then come back to SO with a more focused question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in pandas by plotting a crosstab of your data:

```
import pandas as pd

data=[["30-34","Man"], ["35-39","Man"], ["30-34","Woman"], ["30-34","Man"], ["18-21","Man"], ["55-59","Woman"], ["55-59","Man"], ["55-59","Woman"], ["30-34","Man"], ["22-24","Man"], ["22-24","Man"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Age","Gender"])
pd.crosstab(df['Age'],df['Gender']).plot.bar()
```

Result:

[image: Result]